# How to write a query that selects last specific day and goes back 1 week from there?

Tags: sql, sede

I use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201514/find-answers-to-flag) on SEDE. I have just been editing the `WHERE p.CreationDate > '2014-12-21T00:00:00.001'` like every week to select the last week's records only. So for example previous edits were just changing to 12-21 from 12-14 from 12-7, etc..

I'm trying to edit that part so that I don't have to keep editing it every week.

I was thinking I could do something like

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, p.creationDate, GETDATE()) <= 7
```

which would select only results from the last 7 days.

However, this will only work on like Sunday when SEDE is updated. If I run a query on Wednesday, then this query will be missing three days of results.

How could I write this `where` statement to like find the last nearest Sunday, or is Sunday, and then go back one week from there?

Comment: `WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, p.creationDate, DateAdd(dd, -1, DateAdd(wk, DateDiff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0))) <= 7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find `previous sunday` use this piece of code.

```
select DateAdd(dd, -1, DateAdd(wk, DateDiff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0)) [Previous Sunday]
```

`Where clause` should be something like.

```
Select ... from tablename 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, p.creationDate, DateAdd(dd, -1, DateAdd(wk, DateDiff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0))) <= 7
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions, similar to this.
Replace the GetDate in your where clause with some thing like

```
 Cast(DateAdd(day,-DatePart(weekday,GetDate())+1,GetDate()) as Date)
```

where the +1 is adjusted larger or smaller to move to the specific day of the week you want to start with. The +1 causes this to becaome sunday.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Assuming your db @@DATEFIRST in on sunday (i.e 7)

WHERE p.creationdate >= DATEADD( day, -6 - DATEPART(weekday,GETDATE()), GETDATE() )
```